# Deferred exception after populating global variable from ajax method with $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an asp.net page that loads a chart and some tables.

When the page loads I retrieve some data from a server & make a few ajax calls as shown in the code below.

I have two global variables, RainFall and RainDates that I need to populate.

When the page loads I have a function CalcSummaryStats that makes use of these global values to calculate some statistics.

My understanding (AJAX & Jquery are new to me) is that the ajax requests run asynchronously so the $.ajax method returns before the request is finished, and therefore before the success callback runs.

So after some reading I could use $.when method like the line below,

> $.when(methodRainCont(), methodRainSingle()).then(calcData);

In methodRainCont the chart is draw and in this function at the same time RainDates is populated.

In methodRainSingle my other global variable is populated.

And my understanding is that this means that once both methods have finished running (assuming that includes the success callback) my function calcData is then called. calcData calls another function outside of the $(document).ready block called CalcSummaryStats & this is where my error happens.

It tries the line below

> var cM = RainDates[0].getMonth();

but get this error

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined

So it seems like RainDates is not populated? I thought using $.when would make sure both functions had run successfully before calling calcData?

**My JS file**

```
// my two global variables
var Rainfall = [];
var RainDates = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

 var $opts = $('#optList');

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/UserOptions',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (codes) {
        $.each(codes, function (i, code) {
            $opts.append('<li id="' + code + '">' + code + '</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error ");
    }
});

 function methodRainCont() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/RainContr',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            DrawChart(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

function methodRainSingle() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/RainSingle',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            Rainfall = data;                // setting my global variable values
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}


$.when(methodRainCont(), methodRainSingle()).then(calcData);

function calcData()
{        
    var cords = {
        x: {
            min: RainDates[0],
            max: RainDates[RainDates.length - 1]
        }
    };

    CalcSummaryStats(cords);
}


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `methodRainCont()` and `methodRainSingle()` do not return a promise to be used by `$.when()`, so `calcData()` executes immediately and ajax calls are not finished.

So, inside these functions, replace`$.ajax({` with `return $.ajax({`